# Enable spell check with american dictionary for all buffers

Tags: flycheck, ispell, spell-checking

I have an init file that loads two files: one from customization done from within emacs and other from my custom settings file - `better-defaults.el`.

I have tried various options like `ispell-local-dictionary "en_US"`, `ispell-dictionary "american"` and a few other *flycheck* declarations with `setq-default` inside `better-defaults.el`, but spell check is not working.

How do I enable spellcheck with American dictionary on the fly?

I'm using Emacs 26 on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you install an external spellchecker like `aspell.exe`?  Emacs does not have its own spellchecker per se -- the Lisp files that come with Emacs rely upon the presence of an external program to do the actual spell checking.  The Lisp files just search for a word, but they do not know whether the word is wrong or right ....

Comment: I dont have an external spellchecker installed. Is it possible to use the default Windows 10 dictionary in Emacs?

Comment: Here is a link to a thread describing some problems with `aspell` and perhaps problems also with `hunspell` on Windows 10 when using Emacs:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41892/aspell-with-emacs-26-1-on-ms-windows  The thread contains some other suggestions you may wish to explore.  I have never read anything about native spellchecker support for Emacs on Windows (any version) .... I would guess that this does not exist.